# Man displaying groff control characters

Tags: man, less, groff

Man is displaying groff control characters after I compiled a later version of `groff`. For example, when I try to view `groff`'s man page:

```
GROFF(1)                    General Commands Manual                   GROFF(1)



ESC[1mNAMEESC[0m
       groff - front-end for the groff document formatting system

ESC[1mSYNOPSISESC[0m
       ESC[1mgroff ESC[22m[ESC[1m-abcegijklpstzCEGNRSUVXZESC[22m] [ESC[1m-d ESC[4mESC[22mcsESC[24m] [ESC[1m-D 
ESC[4mESC[22margESC[24m] [ESC[1m-f ESC[4mESC[22mfamESC[24m] [ESC[1m-F ESC[4mESC[22mdirESC[24m]
             [ESC[1m-I ESC[4mESC[22mdirESC[24m] [ESC[1m-K ESC[4mESC[22margESC[24m] [ESC[1m-L ESC[4mESC[22marg
ESC[24m] [ESC[1m-m ESC[4mESC[22mnameESC[24m] [ESC[1m-M ESC[4mESC[22mdirESC[24m] [ESC[1m-n ESC[4mESC[22mnumESC[24m] [ESC[1m-o ESC[4mESC[22mlistESC[24m]
             [ESC[1m-P ESC[4mESC[22margESC[24m] [ESC[1m-r ESC[4mESC[22mcnESC[24m] [ESC[1m-T ESC[4mESC[22mdevESC[24m] [ESC[1m-w ESC[4mESC[22mnameESC[24m] [ESC[1m-W ESC[4mESC[22mnameESC[24m] [ESC[4mfileESC[24m ...]
       ESC[1mgroff -h ESC[22m| ESC[1m--helpESC[0m
       ESC[1mgroff -v ESC[22m| ESC[1m--version ESC[22m[ESC[4moptionESC[24m ...]

ESC[1mDESCRIPTIONESC[0m
       This  document  describes the ESC[1mgroff ESC[22mprogram, the main front-end for the
       ESC[4mgroffESC[24m document formatting system.  The ESC[4mgroffESC[24m program and macro suite is
       the implementation of a ESC[1mroffESC[22m(7) system within the free software collec-
       tion GNU <http://www.gnu.org>.  The ESC[4mgroffESC[24m system has  all  features  of
:
```

Comment: There _isn't_ any `/var/cache/man` when I checked.

Answer (score 4):

Your `man` command is using `groff` to format the page with ANSI color
escape sequences (ISO 6429), and your pagination program (likely `more`
or `less`) is expanding these unprintable characters instead of passing
them unchanged to your terminal screen.

To tell `less` (for example) not to expand these ANSI sequences, use
the `-R` or `--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS` option.  You can often do this by
setting the option you want in the `LESS` environment variable or
perhaps using the `PAGER` environment variable:

```
$ LESS='-R' man groff
$ PAGER='less -R' man groff
```

It might also be an incorrect directive to the underlying `groff`,
causing `groff` (or `grotty`) to issue ANSI escapes when you don't
really want them.  You can tell `man` not to use the escapes by using
something like this:

```
$ man --ascii groff
```

The man page for `grotty` talks in detail about your options for fixing
the problem.